# How to use addFieldToFilter & addFieldToSelect in magento2

Tags: magento2, collection

I need to known how to use `addFieldToFilter` & `addFieldToSelect` in frontend? And can I use like below

```
$searchQuery = $wholeData["searchQuery"] ?? "";
$searchQuery = trim($searchQuery);
$agentCollection = $this->_agents->create()->addNameToSelect();
             
if ($agentId > 0) {
    $agentCollection->addFieldToFilter("id", $agentId);
} else {
    $agentCollection->addFieldToSelect("email")
            ->addFieldToFilter(
                    [
                            ["field"=>"email", "like"=>"%".$searchQuery."%"],
                            ["field"=>"contactno", "like"=>"%".$searchQuery."%"]
                    ]
            );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Followings are my findings about your question:

1. What does **"use addFieldToFilter & addFieldToSelect in frontend."** means?
2. Yes, you can use addFieldToFilter as you define.

   - If **email** column is in your table, then you don't need to add **email** in to select.
   - Use Add field to select when you are using this with the select column in another table when joining.

Answer (score 0):

1) yes you can use this logic in front end but in block classes.
2) yes above logic can be used but it will add OR logic in you case same as following in better way

```
$this->collection->addFieldToFilter(
        ['weight', 'name'],
        [['in' => [1, 3]], ['like' => 'M%']]
    );
```

Can be used as AND logic:

```
$category = $this->collectionFactory->create()
            ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $rootCategoryId)
            ->addFieldToFilter('name', $categoryName)
            ->fetchItem();
```

Comment: what is this addFieldToFilter

Comment: addFieldToFilter is similar to sql part : where name = 'hassan'

Comment: SELECT time FROM list WHERE date = "2020-10-12" GROUP BY time;
HOw would you do this?

Comment: $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('date', $date);
        $collection->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
            ->columns('time');
        $collection->getSelect()->group('time');
git it from here
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295358/magento-2-how-to-do-a-query-on-custom-collection

Comment: what are you doing? in above you are collecting all attributes by using * and the reset again all element  and select 'time'. why don't you put $collection->addAttributeToSelect('time'); ?

Comment: Always use optimized way never select * in attribute selection its huge performance blow

Comment: this is the query i can run in sql = SELECT time FROM list WHERE date = "2020-10-12" GROUP BY time;
But i am using a factory custom one and i dont know how to run a query

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addFieldToFilter` to filter collection data by any available field

Due to performance reasons most collections won't include all fields by default, so you may use `addFieldToSelect` to add the fields you need

For instance, the code in the question adds **email** to collection, so it's included and then it's available to filter  the collection