# Magento 2 how to do a query on custom collection

Tags: collection, factory

SELECT time FROM my_timeslot_list WHERE `date` = "2019-11-12" GROUP BY time;

How do I run this query on collection factory.

```
This is the code  $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('date', $date);
```

But this isn’t correct. Is there anyway I could do the query in collection

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line with your code:

```
$collection->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
    ->columns('time');
$collection->getSelect()->group('time');
```

Comment: To the bottom of my existing code?

Comment: @JackBrooks yes

Comment: Okay I will give this a ago can you explain what this does please too